# Dialog Box with Input Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have a dialog window with an input. I could use the default jQuery-ui one, but I am using one that incorporate bootstrap. However, the input only appears the first time that it is opened, any subsequent times the dialog is opened, the input is missing. How would this be remedied?
Here is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap3-dialog/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker3.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Hello!</h3>
    <div>
        <span>Enter a Zip Code: </span>
        <input type="text" id="zip">
        <button id="getEvents" class="btn btn-primary">Get events!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="datepicker"></div>
    <div id="events"></div>
    <button id="addItemButton">Add an item</button>
    <div id="addItemDialog"><input type="text" id="newItem"></div>
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap3-dialog/js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/calendar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var url,
        year,
        month,
        zip,
        date,
        events = [],
        newItem;

    $("#addItemDialog").hide();

    $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"}).click(function(){
        $("#events").empty();
        date = $(".datepicker").datepicker("getDate");
        //console.dir(date.toISOString().substr(0, 10));
        $(events).each(function(i, event){
            //console.log(event);
            if(event.date.substr(0, 10) === date.toISOString().substr(0, 10)){
                console.log(event.title);
                $("#events").append("<h4 class='event'>" + event.title + "</h4>");
            }
        });
    });

    $("#getEvents").on("click", function () {
        zip = $("#zip").val();
        if(isValidUSZip(zip)){
            zip = zip.substr(0, 5);
            getCalendar();
        }else{
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                message: "You must enter a valid zip code!",
                buttons: [{label:"OK", action: function(dialog){dialog.close();}}],
                draggable: true
            });
        }
    });

    function isValidUSZip(sZip) {
        return /^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$/.test(sZip);
    }




    function getCalendar() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.hebcal.com/hebcal/?v=1&cfg=json&nh=on&nx=on&year=now&month=x&ss=on&mf=on&c=on&zip=" + zip +"&m=72&s=on",
            success: function (data) {
                console.dir(data);
                $(data.items).each(function(index, item){
                    //console.dir(item.date.substr(0, 10));
                    events.push(item);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    $("#addItemButton").on("click", function(){
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            message: $("#newItem"),
            buttons: [{
                label: "Enter",
                action: function(dialog){
                    newItem = $("#newItem").val();
                    events.push({date: new Date(date).toISOString(), title: newItem});
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: can you make working demo?

Comment: Sure, how do I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure how to to that because I'm using various external libraries in my code

Comment: So maby you could show us working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a time and make this fiddle, aparently everything is working fine:

I doubt about this line for a moment, but still uncommented is going right:

```
$(function () {
//"use strict";
var url,
    year,
    month,
    zip,
    date,
    events = [],
    newItem;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r2FyC/3/

Comment: Using your fiddle, the problem remains. Try entering a new item, and then clicking on a new date and click the "enter item" button again. There is no input box in the dialog.